# Having trouble with a linux print statement

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm using linux bash shell to take the age (years) that a user has entered and print out the titled statement with the age in years.

I'm able to calculate the number of days and print it by using

`echo "$age * 365" | bc`

but how do I insert that variable into the statement

"Your age in days is: XXX, where XXX represents the user's age in days."
(XXX is where the age in days is inserted)

This is my full code below that shows the user entering their first and last name, age, and printing a statement based on their age.

```
`#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter first name: "
read first_name
echo "Enter last name: "
read last_name
echo "Enter age: "
read age
echo "Your full name is $first_name $last_name"
if [ "$age" -lt 20 ]; then
echo "You're still under 20 years old."
elif [ "$age" -ge 20 -a "$age" -lt 30 ]; then
echo "You are in your twenties."
elif [ "$age" -ge 30 -a "$age" -lt 40 ]; then
echo "You are in your thirties."
elif [ "$age" -ge 40 ]; then
echo "You are older than 40."
fi

echo "$age * 365 | bc`
```

Comment: ageinday=$(echo "$age * 365" | bc)

Comment: Try pasting your code into [shellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) ...

Comment: Note that for questions like this is is not helpful to read the inputs.  Instead, you should post code that simply specifies the values.  Unless your question is about methods of reading input, don't include that in the question.

Comment: Long `if/elif` chains are almost always easier to read as a `case` statement. eg: `case $((age / 10)) in 0|1) echo "You're under 20";; 2) "You are in your twenties";; *) echo "You are 30 or over";; esac`

Comment: Don't use `-a`; its meaning is ambiguous in certain situations. Just use, e.g., `[ "$age" -ge 20 ] && [ "$age" -lt 30 ]` or `(( age >= 20 && age < 30 ))`.

Answer (score 1):

"how do I insert that variable into the statement?"  You don't have a variable!  But you can get one very easily:

```
age_in_days=$(echo "$age * 365" | bc)
```

although you can also do:

```
age_in_days=$((age * 365))
```

So you can then do either:

```
echo "Your age in days is: $age_in_days"
```

or drop the variable completely and write:

```
echo "Your age in days is: $((age * 365))"
```